# Cannot import library covsirphy

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to import library COVSIRPHY to jupyter notebook following two steps:

1. pip install --upgrade covsirphy (I installed it using terminal in specific environment created in anaconda navigator)

It was installed successfully

2. import covsirphy as cs

I typed in directly in jupyter notebook, but it occured an error:

OSError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file)

It is trying to search a path which does not exists, but physically the file libomp.dylib is located in other path, but I have no idea why it is seeking in this path.
I am wondering whether this library is possible to install on Mac with chip M1.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfYCR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuEFu.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited the post and I hope that now is cleared

Answer (score 0):

Please re-install `libomp` to save 'libomp.dylib' file at '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' or update `PATH` to include the current path.

An alternative:
Because the latest development version of `covsirphy` does not depend on `lightgbm`, try to reinstall the latest version (>= 3.0.0.dev7).

```
pip install --upgrade "git+https://github.com/lisphilar/covid19-sir.git#egg=covsirphy"
```